# Subclipse file commit issue while conflict in eclipse 4.2.0

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

Issue: whenever I try to commit any file that has conflict(showing red), eclipse crashes. I am not able to do any SVN related operation using subclipse. I have to restart eclipse every time. Not sure why this is happening. Let me know if somebody has come across the same issue.

I am using Subclipse 1.8.6. with following eclipse version info.

Eclipse SDK
Version: 4.2.0
Build id: I20120608-1400

Answer (score 0):

I think its a known issue in that release. Have a look here

http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1046&dsMessageId=2937836

Can you try to update to the latest version of subclipse ?

Comment: Shoot! My eclipse is not starting. :)  I got this error on eclipse start up. "Unable to load default SVN Client." I think, while intalling subclipse 1.10.x, it did not over ride the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It works now. I had to reinstall my eclipse. and updated subclipse to 1.10.x. Thanks for your help.